# Accept empty string or string with length of 0 as input using Scanner in Java

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I use Scanner in Java to get user entries such as name, surname, email and tel. The name and surname are required but the email and tel are not required and they can be leaved as empty by user just by hitting enter key.

What I want to do is add a method that will validate if entry is empty or has a length of 0 and if it's the case
when user hits enter the empty string will be accepted by scanner as a valid value.

This is the method I use to validate length of each entry and display an error message if length is under or over the min or max.

```
public static String validateString (String msgSoll, String msgErr, 
               int lngMin, int lngMax) {
          String myString = null;
          
          if (lngMin >= 0 && lngMax >= lngMin) {
             do {
                System.out.print(msgSoll);
                myString = myScanner.nextLine();
                if (myString.length() < lngMin || myString.length() > lngMax) {
                   System.out.println(msgErr);
                }
             } while (myString.length() < lngMin || myString.length() > lngMax);
          }
          return myString;
       }
```

I would appreciate if someone could help me with that method.

Thank's

Comment: What is the problem with that method?

Comment: This method is ok but it's just validating the length of entry. What I want to do is add a method that will validate if entry is empty or has a length of 0 and if it's the case when user hits enter key the empty string will be accepted by scanner as a valid entry.

Comment: So why did you post that method if its ok? Please post the method where you attempted the validation. From your post above I can't figure out what do you need

Comment: I just added an else if statement to check if value is blank or length is 0 and add that condition to do while loop and now it seems to work. Do you have any other idea to make my code better ?                                                                                              if(chaine.isBlank() || chaine.length() == 0) {
                     chaine = "Empty";
                } else if (chaine.length() < lngMin || chaine.length() > lngMax) {
                    System.out.println(msgErr);
                }
          ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`String#isBlank`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#isBlank()) (available from Java-11) to test the input.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    static Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println("Your name: " + validateString("Enter your name: "));
    }

    public static String validateString(String message) {
        String input = "";
        do {
            System.out.print(message);
            input = myScanner.nextLine();
            if (input.isBlank()) {
                System.out.println("It's an empty string.");
            }
        } while (input.isBlank());
        return input;
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter your name: 
It's an empty string.
Enter your name: 
It's an empty string.
Enter your name: Hello
Your name: Hello
```

**Note:** if the version of your Java is lower than `11`, you can use `if (input.isEmpty() || input.trim().length() == 0)` as the condition.